# Rails 3 & Encrypted Strings Gem - getting OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3 and the encrypted_strings gem, when try the following:

```
"wC6234sdf234234cCY1Lag==\n".decrypt(:symmetric, :key => "mykeynottelling")
```

I get this error:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: bad decrypt
```

This does not however happen with Ruby 1.8.7. I'm a little lost on this, does anyone see what might be causing this?

**UPDATE 1:**

If I encrypt a string in ruby 1.8.7:

```
"password".encrypt(:symmetric, :key => "www.buyandsell.ie") # output is "hr0aZUZTa7x1gQL8ZMI/dQ==\n"
```

and try to decrypt that in ruby 1.9.2 I get a "bad decrypt" error, but I if paste it into my IRB console in ruby 1.8.7 and try to decrypt it, it works.

**Update 2:**

OpenSSL is different between my ruby 1.9.3 and 1.8.7 boxes, could this cause this error?

Comment: Remove the newline character at the end of your string.  Newlines are not base-64 characters.

Comment: @mcfinnigan - I tried this but still getting the bad decrypt error

Comment: i am getting the similar problem in upgrading a rails app based running on ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 2.2.3. Did you find any solution for the issue?
All seems ok in code, seems like be some internal change.

Please let me know if somebody know the cause of it, i am stuck on this from last few days.

Comment: Are you using the same key that was used to encrypt the string? This error usually occurs when the encryption and decryption keys don't match. I tried encrypting a simple string in Ruby 1.8.7, and decrypted the same in Ruby 1.9.3 / 2.2.2 without any issues. The only reason this could be failing would be a complex key which is creating an encoding problem while encrypting the strings. Can you please share a case to repro this issue?

Comment: Thanks for reverting back.
I too suspect something related to encoding but not with key encoding but something at file bytes array. 
I stopped digging in cause and moved to use AWS S3 SSE instead.
So i pulled all files in Rake task and uploaded those to new location with SSE using AWS:KMS

Comment: Just a hunch, but the way ruby treats source files has changed somewhat with the versions. This might be an issue unless you are using explicit file encodings with magic comments. The probability of this being an issue rises if your key included special characters. HTH!

Comment: have you tried `"wC6234sdf234234cCY1Lag==\n".decrypt`? From their documentation it does not look like `decrypt` has parameters being passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue upgrading from 1.9.3 to 2.2.2 dealing with the [Symmetric Encryption](https://github.com/reidmorrison/symmetric-encryption) gem.  The root cause ended up being the fact that the gem used Ruby's marshaling library, which had changed between versions.

I ultimately had to decrypt all of the data in 1.9.3 before upgrading to 2.2.2, which proved to be a miserable experience.

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html),

> Marshaled data has major and minor version numbers stored along with the object information. In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number.